# Date showing up as NaN in IE?

Tags: javascript

I know this has been covered a bit online, but I'm still not too sure how to modify this particular piece of code unfortunately:

```
timeCreated: function(dateString) {     
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

    var hh = date.getHours();
    var m = date.getMinutes();
    var dd = "AM";  
    var h = hh;

    if (h >= 12) {
        h = hh-12;
        dd = "PM";
    }
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    }

    return h + ':' + date.getMinutes().toString() + ' ' + dd + ' ' + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ', ' + date.getDate().toString() + ', ' +  date.getFullYear().toString();


}
```

The dateString is outputting as `Tue Nov 06 23:29:33 +0000 2012`.

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble with this and the only 'safe' solution I found was to give `Date()` the individual values for year, month, etc. You can do this by using `.split()` on the date string appropriately. You can get the exact syntax at the [4th constructor example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: @MartyWallace thanks I'll take a look at those example.

Comment: @YogendraSingh it outputs as Nan in IE.

Comment: @YogendraSingh as stated in my question, its `Tue Nov 06 23:29:33 +0000 2012`

Comment: Do you mean that this line `var date = new Date(dateString);` sets the `date` variable to `NaN` in IE when the `dateString` parameter is `"Tue Nov 06 23:29:33 +0000 2012"`?

Answer (score 2):

Your input date format doesn't match any of the standard formats hence `IE` is unable to parse it i.e. **unable to construct the right date object.**

Since your `Date` object is not constructed properly, all methods calls such as `date.getHours();` and `date.getMinutes();` are returning NaN.

If you use the date string in acceptable format e.g. dateString = "Nov 06 2012 23:29:33 +0000", **it works properly.**

If you want to support custom format base data parsing, look at 
http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/, which has a big custom method `getDateFromFormat(val,format)` to convert any date string in specific format to the Date object. Please have a look and see if that helps.

Comment: IE doesn't work with the ["standard" date strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) either, which is one reason why date strings should be manually parsed. And the date string format you suggest is not consistent with ECMA-262.

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of `dateString`?

Built–in support for parsing date strings varies among browsers from poor to awful. Far better to manually parse the string to turn it into a Date object, then go from there. If you provide the string format, further help can be provided.